# why android requires jvm

Tags: java, android, jvm

As long as android uses special virtual machine "Dalvik Virtual Machine", why it requires regular JVM to be installed in order to develop android apps. ?
what does android use JVM for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android SDK uses the regular JVM to run and build your Apps.

It's not the same the app runtime environment (Dalvik) and the SDK runtime environment (JDK).

Answer (score 2):

First JVM:

Android SDK tools like emulator, android etc (might as I am not sure, they can be written in native language too) and tools like Eclipse need JVM to run themselves.

JDK:

Android SDK needs JDK to compile your code first to .class files using Java JDK compiler and then these .class files are converted to .dex files which is specific for Dalvik.